# @XmlDiscriminatorNode/@XmlDescriminatorValue not working on WebLogic Server

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x, moxy

Following are the classes I am using for create sub classes using MOXy JAXB conversion on WebLogic 10.3.2 version. I am using the EclipseLink 2.4.1 MOXy for generating the XML. I am unable to generate the type attribute in the following code.  Let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

I am using EclipseLink MOXy 2.4.1 and WebLogic 10.3.2 and MOXy 2.4.1 is configured in the WebLogic

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

**Subclass**

```java
package forum13831189;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("xyz")
public class XyzEntity extends BaseEntity {

    public XyzEntity() {
        super();
    }

}
```

**Another Sub Class**

```java
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("Abc")
public class AbcEntity extends BaseEntity {
}
```

**RESTful Web Service Class:**

```java
@GET
@Path("/xyz")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Representation getAccount() throws CPAException {
    Representation rep = new Representation();
    BaseEntity entity = new XyzEntity();
    entity.setFirstName("first-name");
    entity.setLastName("last-name");
    rep.setEntity(entity);
    return rep;
}

@XmlRootElement
static class Representation {
    private BaseEntity entity;

    public BaseEntity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public void setEntity(BaseEntity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

The above is generating the following XML.

```xml
<representation>
     <firstName>first-name</firstName>
      <lastName>last-name</lastName>
 </representation>
```

The attribute type is not generated in the above.

---

Thanks a lot. Yes, I missed jaxb.properties in the above.
Also, Yes when I use the PUT or POST, when XML is de-serialized, it is not able to create the subclasses if @XmlSeeAlso is not present.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple items that may be causing you problems.

**BaseEntity**

By default a JAX-RS implementation creates a `JAXBContext` on the return type or parameter of the service method, in this case `Represenatation`.  When processing the domain model the JAXB impl will also pull in referred types such as `BaseEntity`.  It can't automatically pull in subclasses so we can use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to reference those.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
@XmlSeeAlso({AbcEntity.class, XyzEntity.class})
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

Also since `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` are MOXy extensions you need to make sure you specify MOXy as your JAXB provider.  This is done by adding a file named `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

Below is a standalone example that mimics what your RESTful service does.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Representation.class);

        Representation rep = new Representation();
        BaseEntity entity = new XyzEntity();
        entity.setFirstName("first-name");
        entity.setLastName("last-name");
        rep.setEntity(entity);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(rep, System.out);
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    static class Representation {
        private BaseEntity entity;

        public BaseEntity getEntity() {
            return entity;
        }

        public void setEntity(BaseEntity entity) {
            this.entity = entity;
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  See that the `type` attribute is now present.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<representation>
   <entity type="xyz">
      <firstName>first-name</firstName>
      <lastName>last-name</lastName>
   </entity>
</representation>
```

**For More Information**

- [Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)
- [JAXB and Inheritance - MOXy Extension @XmlDescriminatorNode/@XmlDescrimintatorValue](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html)
- [Updating EclipseLink in WebLogic](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/10/updating-eclipselink-in-weblogic.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed jaxb.properties in the above.

Comment: In the above example, I am using same method for producing XML and JSON as @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })    Can you please let me know how to configure MOXY JSON to be used.

Comment: @user1896301 - The following is the best way to configure MOXy as your JSON provider:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html